# How to implement for each with an iterator that accepts an argument?

Tags: java, foreach, iterator, iterable

I'm implementing a custom `JarFile` class. One of the features is that it can limit the iteration of its contents to a subset by giving the starting path.

Simplified class example:

```
public class JarFile Iterable<JarEntry>
{
   // Wraps java.util.jar.JarFile internally
   java.util.jar.JarFile jarFile;
   ..
   
   @Override
   public Iterator<JarEntry> iterator() {
      return new JarIterator(jarFile);
   }
   
   public Iterator<JarEntry> iterator(String startPath) {
      return new JarIterator(jarFile, startPath);
   }
}
```

For example, a jar file contains some paths:

```
a/file1.class
b/file2.class
c/file3.class
```

Iterating over the jar file normally will provide all of the entries contained therein. But my `JarIterator` also provides a constructor with a `path` argument which limits iteration to only a subset and its children.

For example, this will output the same list as above:

```
JarFile jf = new JarFile("Test.jar")

for (JarEntry je : jf)
   System.out.println(je.getName());
```

I can access the alternate iterator like this:

```
JarIterator it = jf.iterator("b/");
   
while (it.hasNext()) {
   JarEntry je = it.next();
   
   System.out.println(je.getName());
}
```

The output is instead this subset entry:

```
b/file2.class
```

Everything already works as it is but I would like to take advantage of Java's `for` keyword but this only works with the default no-args constructor.

Is there a way to make it work with my custom iterator without having to call `hasNext()` and `next()`?

Answer (score 0):

NB: I think this is bad API design - see below.

There is no way to haev a nice API for the users of this library with a method named `iterator`. You have a few options, but the most obvious one:

### Don't return an iterator, return an iterable.

This meshes with my advice below that your method is a bad design in any case, but if you must have it, that it has a bad name. Once you address the name, you can return iterables instead:

```
for (JarEntry je : jf.filterByPrefix("b/")) { ... }
```

The `filterByPrefix` method would return an `Iterable<JarEntry>`; this needs to be an object that has an `iterator()` (no-args!) method that returns an iterator that iterates only over the stated entries. It'd be trivial; imagine you had that `iterator(String prefix)` method:

```
public Iterable<JarFile> filterByPrefix(String prefix) {
    return () -> iterator(prefix);
}
```

---

Some introspection on why this doesn't sound like good API design:

> `jf.iterator("b/");`

Not sure this is great design; once you go down this path, where is the `iterator` method that lets me iterate only files whose uncompressed size is no higher than the stated value? While we're at it, where is the one that lets me only iterate files whose filename has a prime length? A ridiculous question, but I'm trying to get you to realize that pre-defining the filter conditions is suboptimal: You have no idea what people might want to filter on, so now you get into a style debate with your library's users: If there is a need to filter, and you provide this filtering via this iterator method, should one always use that? But that's inconsistent. Now the code to iterate over a jar file, filtering out all entries that are larger than 1mb, looks *completely different* from code that filters out stuff that doesn't start with `"foo"`. Having two ways to accomplish the same thing is usually bad news. Better not to do that.

If there is a pressing performance argument, this makes sense, but there isn't. Your impl can't skip stuff that doesn't start with `"b/"` any faster than:

```
    if (!je.getName().startsWith("b/")) continue;
```

can, and that is just one line of java code that you're trying to save.

If you must, at least call it `iteratorByPrefix` or something. How is one supposed to guess that `iterator("b/")` iterates over all entries that *start* with `"b/"`? Why isn't that 'iterate all entries that contain the text b/', or perhaps even all entries whose text content starts with b/, or that end in b/, or have an associated zip tag with b/?

If you have a pressing performance need or just cannot stand that one-liner filter `if`, then instead of filtering by prefix, why not filter by function?

```
for (JarEntry je : jf.onlyByName(n -> n.startsWith("b/")) {}
```

while you're at it, perhaps also make an `only` method that passes in not the name but the entire JarEntry object. The parameter's type would be `Predicate<String>` or `Predicate<JarEntry>`.